# Slicing Multi Index Header DataFrames in Python With Custom Sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get a handle on slicing. I've got the following dataframe, df:

```
    Feeder # 1                               Feeder # 2
    TimeStamp   MW     Month   Day   Hour    TimeStamp      MW     Month     Day    Hour
0   2/3         1.2    1       30    22        2/3          2.4    1         30     22 
1   2/4         2.3    1       31    23        2/3          4.1    1         31     23
2   2/5         3.4    2       1     0         2/3          3.7    2         1      0
```

There are 8 feeders in total.

If I want to select all the MW columns in all the Feeders, I can do:

```
df.xs('MW', level=1, axis=1,drop_level=False)
```

If I want Feeders 2 through 4, I can do:

```
df.loc[:,'Feeder #2':'Feeder #4']
```

BUT if I want columns MW through Day in just Feeders 2 through 4 via:

```
df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['Feeder #2':'Feeder #4','MW':'Day']]
```

I get the following error.

```
MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)
```

So if I sort the dataframe, then I'm able to do:

```
df.sortlevel(level=0,axis=1).loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['Feeder #2':'Feeder #4','Day':'MW']]
```

But sorting the dataframe destroys the original order of level 1 in the header-- everything gets alphabetized (lexsorted in Python-speak?). And my desired contents get jumbled: `'Day':'MW'` yields the  `Day`, `Hour` and `MW` columns. But what I want is `'MW':'Day'` which would yield the `MW`, `Month`, and `Day` columns.

So my question is: is it possible to slice through my dataframe and preserve the order of the columns? Alternatively, can I lexsort the dataframe, perform the slices I need and then put the dataframe back in its original order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `CategoricalIndex` to keep the order:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

level0 = "Feeder#1 Feeder#2 Feeder#3 Feeder#4".split()
level1 = "TimeStamp   MW     Month   Day   Hour".split()

idx0 = pd.CategoricalIndex(level0, level0, ordered=True)
idx1 = pd.CategoricalIndex(level1, level1, ordered=True)

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([idx0, idx1])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 20)), columns=columns)
```

Then you can do this:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice["Feeder#2":"Feeder#3", "MW":"Day"]]
```

**edit**

to convert the levels to `CategoricalIndex`:

```
columns = df.columns
for i in range(columns.nlevels):
    level = pd.unique(columns.get_level_values(i))
    cidx = pd.CategoricalIndex(level, level, sorted=True)
    print(cidx)
```

Comment: Hey this is great, exactly what I was looking for. But now I'm having a different problem. Instead of manually specifying the content for level0 and level1, I used level0 = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.levels[0],ordered=True) and level1=pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns.levels[0],ordered=True). Even though the order of the second level in the multiindex is **TimeStamp**, **MW** etc, df.columns.levels[0] automatically alphabetizes the order. Is there a way to call the .column method and preserve the original order?

Comment: Ok, this displays the order that I want: df[df.columns.levels[0][0]].columns.tolist() but it isn't pretty. Is there a more elegant way to print out the second header columns in the original order in the dataframe?

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It's exactly what I need!